# Java stream differences of lists

Tags: java, list, java-8, compare, java-stream

I have a class of Item with fields date, id, and action. In my case, I have the list of old items and another list which includes old items and also new items, so I want to filter out old items so I wouldn't mind them. For example, I iterate over new items and only use the ones which don't belong in the old items list.

With for loop it looks something like this, but I want to rewrite it functional way

```
    List<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item item : newList) {
        for (Item oldItem : oldList) {
            if (!item.getDate().equals(oldItem.getDate()) && !item.getId().equals(oldItem.getId()) && !item.getAction().equals(oldItem.getAction())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: WHY is "everybody always" trying to use streams for no reason other than "they are cool and hip" without any actual requirement / use? Maybe look at how streams work and what functionalities they provide, you have not shown any effort on your own migrating the loops to streams.

Comment: If you want to remove from one list items from other list you can always use `list.removeAll(otherList)`. Just make sure your items can be compared properly with equals method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I suggest implementing an `equals` method in your `Item` class, to avoid that complicated condition (which I'm not sure is correct, BTW).

Second of all, to make the search more efficient, put the elements of the old list in a `HashSet`, to allow constant time lookup. This will require overriding both `equals` and `hashCode` of `Item` class.

Finally the code will look like this:

```
List<Item> filteredList = 
    newList.stream()
           .filter(i -> !oldList.contains(i)) // oldList should be replaced with a HashSet 
                                              // for better performance
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With `HashSet`:

```
Set<Item> oldSet = new HashSet<>(oldList);
List<Item> filteredList = 
    newList.stream()
           .filter(i -> !oldSet.contains(i)) 
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Regarding your condition:

```
if (!item.getDate().equals(oldItem.getDate()) && !item.getId().equals(oldItem.getId()) && !item.getAction().equals(oldItem.getAction()))
```

It appears wrong, since if two Items having different ID will have the same Date (or Action), they will fail the test.

I believe you intended to write :

```
if (!item.getDate().equals(oldItem.getDate()) || !item.getId().equals(oldItem.getId()) || !item.getAction().equals(oldItem.getAction()))
```

This means that two Items are considered different from each other if they differ in at least one of the 3 properties.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should implement the `equals()` method (and `.hashCode()` as well) in your `Item` class so you can compare items correctly, for example it will be needed when using `List`'s **[`.contains()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))**.

Then you can use `.contains()` method to test if the current item exists in the `oldList`, and filter the items based on that result.

With Java 8  your code should look like this:

```
List<Item> result = newList.stream()                
        .filter(line -> !oldList.contains(line))    
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:**

Note that the use of `stream` here isn't really necessary as you can just implement this by using `List` methods, such as [`.retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) which will allow you to filter the `newList` in a better way.

Comment: It should be noted that if you implement equals you have to implement hashCode as well!

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Thank you for pointing it out. Yes of course, `.hashCode` should be implemented along with `.equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need streams for this task. Just use [`List.removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method, which does exactly what you want:

```
oldList.removeAll(newList);
```

This requires the `Item` class to implement the `equals()` method, so that elements can be compared for equality and be removed.

If you don't want to mutate your original `oldList`, you can create a new list and then remove elements from it:

```
List<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
filteredList.removeAll(newList);
```

Another more functional*ish* way to do it would be by using the [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
oldList.removeIf(item -> newList.contains(item));
```

Or just:

```
oldList.removeIf(newList::contains);
```

This still requires the `Item` class to implement the `equals()` method. However, it would also be inefficient, since `List.contains` would need to traverse the whole `newList` to check if each item of `oldList` belongs to it. A more efficient approach would be to use a `HashSet`:

```
Set<Item> newSet = new HashSet<>(newList);
```

Then, use `removeIf` as above:

```
oldList.removeIf(newSet::contains);
```

This approach not only requires the `Item` class to implement the `equals()` method, but also the `hashCode` method, which must conform to the `Object` class contract with regard to equality.